# Элемент из массива в props vue js

Tags: vue.js

Есть ли возможность из массива items, завести переменную item.id (в props)?

```
props: {
 items: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => []
 }
},
```

И верстка, на всякий случай

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
  <div class='bestsellers-item__sticker'>
    <img :src='item.img'>
  </div>
  <span> {{ item.id }}
</div>
```

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема то? Вызывайте ваш компонент, пробрасывайте items и вперед `<my-component :items="items" />`

Comment: Именно в пропсах деструктурировать нельзя - можно либо описать пропс принимающий единичный/множественный `id` (и соотв. значение передавать в компонент), либо ввести в компоненте computed свойство которое будет мапить входной массив в массив `id`.

Comment: <my-component :items="items.map(x => x.id)" /> ?